# EAR file and ValidationMessages.properties

Tags: validation, jakarta-ee, ear

We have separate EAR and WAR files for our application and I need to package the `ValidationMessages.properties` file into the EAR file.

I tried to put it in a JAR inside the EAR file (with the beans or in JAR in the `lib` directory) or to put it directly at the root of the file with no success (the file is not found).

Where should I put the file (or files in case of several languages)?

**Edit** EAR sample structure:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/application.xml
META-INF/build.properties
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

doi-ejb.jar                      <-- Application's EJBs
lakshmi-ejb.jar                  <-- Framework EJB's
lakshmi-std-cmp-ejb.jar          <-- Framework EJB's

lib/
lib/config.jar
lib/doi-int-test-lib.jar
lib/doi-lib.jar
lib/doi-unit-test-lib.jar
lib/lakshmi-lib.jar
lib/lakshmi-std-cmp-lib.jar
```

Comment: Which module(s) in the above sketch need(s) to read the properties file?

Comment: doi-ejb.jar and then it should be accessible also by an optional WAR. Or do I have to package it twice if I need it in the EAR *and* the WAR?

Comment: Yes, I think, you will have to bundle the file into both doi-ejb.jar and war files.

Comment: @BimaleshJha OK I will package it twice. Then it will go in `WEB-INF/classes` in the WAR and where in the EAR? In the class path of one of the JARs with the EJBs?

Comment: keep it in the doi-ejb.jar at root folder.

Comment: @BimaleshJha Post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you will have to bundle the file into both **doi-ejb.jar** and war files. Keep it under `WEB-INF/classes` in the WAR and in the **doi-ejb.jar** at root folder. You can modify your ANT/build script to copy the same source file at both these locations. That way you will not duplicate your coding/maintenance effort for this properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the `ValidationMessages.properties` file in **your WAR file**, into the `WEB-INF/classes` folder?

This is the path where the web container looks for non-packaged resources.

Comment: In the WAR it works without problems. Since the bean validation has nothing to do with the web fronted (and we deploy separated WAR and EAR files). It should be possible to deploy an application without a WAR file if there is no web frontend.

Comment: Do you have an EJB module in your EAR file as well? It would be nice if you could sketch the structure of your EAR file content.

Comment: I added a sample structure of my EARs